# Adding a Constraint to a Monad Result Type

Tags: haskell, monads

I would like to create a type that is an instance of `Monad` such that the result type can only be an instance of a specific typeclass. I would like to be able to write something like

```
data T a = T a
class C a where
    ...

instance Monad T where
    return :: (C a) => a -> m a
    return x = ...
    (>>=) :: (C a, C b) => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
    p >>= f = ...
```

In the actual code that I'm working on, I need a typeclass constraint on the result type so that a specific function from the typeclass is available in the definitions for `return` and `(>>=)`.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The standard `Monad` class prevents adding constraints. It's a known issue, preventing e.g. `Monad Set` since `Set a` requires `Ord a` to work. One needs to use a more general "constrained monad" or "indexed monad" typeclass, at the cost of being incompatible with the standard monad class.

Comment: @chi Thank you for your helpful comment. I found [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-monads-0.5.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Constrained.html#t:Monad). It looks a lot like what I was looking for and has a lot of other useful features like a "constrained functor" typeclass, a "constrained applicative functor" typeclass, and the ability to use do-notation.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question -- it is allowed by SO's policy, and can be useful to others (and get you some rep).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @chi's comment, the best solution is probably to use either constrained monads or indexed monads. Both solutions have the caveat of having to work around the standard library, but it can be done with workarounds such as rebinding syntax using the `RebindableSyntax` extension for example. The best example of constrained monads I was able to find was the [constrained-monads](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-monads) package available on Hackage, while the best example I was able to find of indexed monads was a post at [Kwang's Haskell Blog](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-12-indexed-monads.html).